# Identical dictionaries in DataFrame all changing at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm working on a project and currently experiencing an issue with populating some dictionaries within a DataFrame. The problem is more complicated but essentially the main issue can be simplified as follows:

I have a DataFrame of dictionaries, all of which initially empty, say

```
example = pd.DataFrame([[dict()] * 2], index=range(0, 3))
```

```
    0   1   

0   {}  {}  
1   {}  {}  
2   {}  {}
```

When I attempt to add a (key, value) item to one dictionary at position [0][0], all dictionaries that are identical to the one I'm attempting to change will experience the same behaviour, i.e. add an entry of key 'char' and value 'a':

```
example.iloc[0][0]['char'] = 'a'
```

```
          0               1         
0   {'char': 'a'}   {'char': 'a'}   
1   {'char': 'a'}   {'char': 'a'}
2   {'char': 'a'}   {'char': 'a'}
```

I'm assuming this behaviour is caused by using `[[dict()] * 2]` in my DataFrame initialization, but I'm not familiar enough with Python to understand why. Is Python creating one dictionary and passing references to it to populate the DataFrame? If so, how could I initialise it to create individual dictionaries? I found that I can create a deep copy of each dictionary before processing them, i.e. `example.applymap(lambda d: copy.deepcopy(d))`, but I'm curious if there is a way of doing it without resorting to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a DataFrame of dictionaries, all of which initially empty

If you multiply a list with an integer, you do *not* make a deep copy, you just copy the references to a new list. This thus means that you made a *single* dictionary, not two identical ones. So you have one dictionary, and all the six cells in the dataframe refer to the *same* dictionary. If you modify that dictionary, of course all the cells see that change.

You can use list comprehension to make different dictionaries, for example:

```
example = pd.DataFrame([[{} for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)], index=range(0, 3))
```

or for an arbitrary length `m` rows and `n` columns:

```
example = pd.DataFrame([[{} for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)])
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
example = pd.DataFrame([[dict(),dict()] for _ in range(3)] , index=range(0, 3))
```

All the elements in your list refer to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

example = pd.DataFrame([[{} for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)], index=range(0, 3))

use this as an solution.
thanks